# How can I handle URLs with Prototype? Like http://mywebserver/#page-4

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, prototypejs

I'm currently creating a web application using the great Prototype JS library; and my HTML will be generated through Prototype's DOM tools.

The problem is that the back-button from the browser will not work because the user is - technically speaking - always on the same page. I saw that i.e. Google's Gmail uses # in their URLS so that you can copy/paste the url or use the browsers back button.

How can I do this? Is there a simple way? I assume not, because I was googling and there were some workarounds, but I wonder if Prototype has something in-built?

Thanks

Comment: If your links actually go to that hash, wouldn't the back button still work? And you'd still be on the same page, so you wouldn't have to reload everything. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for something like [history.js](http://tools.assembla.com/history/browser/).

Comment: Well, sort of. I want that the URL in the browser bar changes so you can send someone a link to a specific part of the page.

Comment: @Daniel, History.js is correct for what you're after. What you're after is not a quick simple 5 minute lesson, but one that requires thought. https://github.com/balupton/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling